# Shall we help out the e-book/e-reader proposal?

Tags: discussion

The Area 51 proposal for [E-Books and E-Readers](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/e-books-and-e-book-readers) is currently in commitment.  There's overlap with us, as it covers not just the devices but producing content for those formats.  This strikes me as an area where we can help each other out.

If you commit to an Area 51 proposal you are promising to participate for three months (once the site goes into beta) and to ask and/or answer at least 10 questions.

Comment: [Here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46400/e-books-and-e-book-readers?referrer=hzLDccp2_Ik4MsQTKsuBzA2) is my referrer link, in case you want to give me a little Area 51 rep when you commit. :-) No obligations, of course, and I encourage others to post their referrer links here too!

Comment: I have a few doubts on Area 51. A lot of content seems related and I'm not sure people will use it, instead this one. I, myself, wouldn't choose to split eContent into a separate site... But that's only my opinion

Comment: Those questions are still on-topic and thus welcome here.  I don't know if the site will really have enough questions to be sustainable, but since the scope also includes topics that don't have a home on SE now, it seems worth a shot.  This won't disrupt us but I figured some of us might also be interested in that site.

Comment: I see... I guess itt's the Google+ effect. I think it's better than facebook but I still don't use G+ because nobody uses G+, and what good is a social network if there nobody is using it? It can be that Area 51 will start slow and grow, but it can also be that people won't use it because they won't get the same speed and quantity in replies what turns out to be a vicious site. Only the future will tell.

Answer (score 3):

I think there would be some overlap, but if the site were to launch I see the writing oriented questions focusing more on marketing, typography and formatting, various publishing platforms (e.g. Leanpub) and possibly distribution related issues. From the proposal, it's more about the logistics of writing than writing itself - they seem to assume that you're capable of putting something interesting in the book.

Ever since the closing of our gadget related site, there really hasn't been a home for questions about simply using an ebook reader, so I can see why it's getting some traction on that end.

If it manages to gain critical mass, sure - I'd definitely consider it a sort of sister site. It seems like it picks up where Writers SE leaves off. You bled, you cried, you sweated; now you have something to publish and need more help.

I'm .. uncertain that the topic will be sustainable, but do feel free to commit to the private beta provided that you've got some real world questions to ask or expertise to share :) Still, I'm not certain many parts of that scope would be off topic here, it seems like there just hasn't been much interest in it.